# Selenium Test is slower and mvn build is faster on Virtual Machine

Tags: selenium

I am running two tasks(mvn build and test) on hardware and virtual machine. mvn-build is faster on the virtual machine as compare to on hardware. And test-execution is slower on Virtual machine as compare to Hardware.

I am using Selenium WebDriver for tests.

VM is on Openstack

Comment: What are your hardware and VM specs?
In general if you have the same source code the machines specs and internet speed effect the execution times.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with 12 cores CPU and 24GB of Ram, For me, it's surprising that why it's building faster on VM.

Comment: It's a powerful machine, I suggest you to get the builds logs and find the execution durations in both, maybe slow internet makes the difference on online mode while downloading the dependencies/packages.

Comment: In the context of downloading dependencies, In my mvn build job there are aslo lots of dependencies that are downloaded for maven cache etc....